# Can I add a button to gmail to run a google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am trying to create a button in gmail to run the following google apps script code:[Google Apps Script Code](https://github.com/niawdeleon/google-apps-scripts/blob/master/Code.gs)

This code allows the extracting and backing up of images embedded in emails.

I have used the code and added it to a project in script.google.com and it currently works.  I would now like to add it as a gmail addon so it can be executed whenever needed within gmail itself.

I have followed the guide here: [Quickstart: Gmail Add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/quickstart/), but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

The google apps script code and the gmail addons are new to me, but any help appreciated.  Be gentle..

Thanks.

Comment: I think it would work if you modify it for only the message that triggers the gmail-addon.

Comment: 'It doesn't seem to be working for me.' Is not a useful description of your problem. Try taking a look at [ask] and [mcve]. By the way, I did that example about a year ago and it worked for me.

Comment: Hi @Cooper, thanks for the input. How best to alter it for only the message that triggers the gmail-addon?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well I don’t think you can add a button to the Gmail UI unless you do it through Gmail Addon.